# Css change to remove div element wrapping select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This has some code wrapped inside

```
table and then form, fieldset, label
```

now i want to unwrap the select tag using the code of the jquery i am using.

I really do not want to refer the `br` tag which i am doing in my fiddle code, is there any other way of doing the same thing

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#Container2').find('table form fieldset label').find('br').find('select').unwrap();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="Container2">
  <table>
    <form>
      <fieldset>
        <div>
          <label>YEARS</label>
          <br>
          <div>
            <select name="q1" id="q1">
              <option value="0">- All -</option>
              <option value="5">5 yr.</option>
              <option value="6">6 yr.</option>
              <option value="7">7 yr.</option>
              <option value="8">8 yr.</option>
              <option value="10">10 yr.</option>
              <option value="11">11 yr.</option>
            </select>
            to
            <select name="q2" id="q2">
              <option value="0">- All -</option>
              <option value="5">5 yr.</option>
              <option value="6">6 yr.</option>
              <option value="7">7 yr.</option>
              <option value="8">8 yr.</option>
              <option value="10">10 yr.</option>
              <option value="11">11 yr.</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </table>
</div>
```

Update #1 - removes the div also if the select is not wrapped (following case)

```
<div id="tableContainer2"><table><form><fieldset><div><label>YEARS</label><br><select class="form_body" name="q1" id="q1">
<option value="0">- All -</option>
<option value="5">5 yr.</option>
<option value="6">6 yr.</option>
<option value="7">7 yr.</option>
<option value="8">8 yr.</option>
<option value="10">10 yr.</option>
<option value="11">11 yr.</option>
</select>
 to 
<select name="q2" id="q2">
<option value="0">- All -</option>
<option value="5">5 yr.</option>
<option value="6">6 yr.</option>
<option value="7">7 yr.</option>
<option value="8">8 yr.</option>
<option value="10">10 yr.</option>
<option value="11">11 yr.</option>
</select>
    </div></fieldset></form></table>
    </div>
```

Comment: Always post your code in your question. Also, your question is unclear.

Comment: Not sure why you'd refer to the `br` tag at all (or the `label`), since the `select` tag is outside of those.

Comment: well yeah, i am noob in this css and jquery so that's was the point of my question

Comment: Right, but regardless of CSS and jQuery -- just looking at the HTML -- the `label` and the `br` have nothing to do with this. They're nearby, but they don't contain anything.

Comment: Can you change the HTML? If so why not just give them ids

Answer (score 1):

If (as I *think* you're asking) you just want to pull the `select` tags out of their parent `div`, you'll want:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // find a div within a fieldset within #Container2, and *direct* descendant
  // selects within that div
  //
  $('#Container2 fieldset div > select').unwrap();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="Container2">
  <table>
    <form>
      <fieldset>
        <div>
          <label>YEARS</label>
          <br>
          <div>
            <select name="q1" id="q1">
              <option value="0">- All -</option>
              <option value="5">5 yr.</option>
              <option value="6">6 yr.</option>
              <option value="7">7 yr.</option>
              <option value="8">8 yr.</option>
              <option value="10">10 yr.</option>
              <option value="11">11 yr.</option>
            </select>
            to
            <select name="q2" id="q2">
              <option value="0">- All -</option>
              <option value="5">5 yr.</option>
              <option value="6">6 yr.</option>
              <option value="7">7 yr.</option>
              <option value="8">8 yr.</option>
              <option value="10">10 yr.</option>
              <option value="11">11 yr.</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: its working but it is also removing the elements of the other form tags like: edit it original question